# Make all list item same height - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the below code to list the cart items in a grid.

http://www.bootply.com/113898#

But the three vertical columns are of different heights in the same row  when Product Name is a long text. Want the row to have the height of the largest li item.   I tried display:table for li but it's not fixing it.
What css changes i need to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to equalise those h4's dynamically, but I reckon just set a min height on them as I have in your example: http://www.bootply.com/113898#

```
h4 {min-height: 100px;}
```

On responsive, say whenever your columns all go to 100%, set your h4 to min-height: none to allow them all to be whatever height the text makes them.